# Tradução adequada para a tag "Cross-browser"

Tags: debate, tradução, tags

A tag [cross-browser](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-browser) é utilizada para identificar problemas cuja solução deverá contemplar o seu funcionamento nos diferentes navegadores disponíveis.

## Problema

Antes de criar esta tag, achei melhor vir aqui definir o nome da mesma de forma a evitar futura manutenção à tag e/ou perguntas relacionadas.

## Pergunta

Em Português, qual a tradução adequada para o nome desta tag mediante o que tem vindo a ser definido sobre as tags?

Answer (score 14):

Eu "traduziria" como:

[cross-browser](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-browser)

Pelo menos no Brasil, é assim que dizemos (como é em Portugal?). Qualquer tradução seria mais confusa que o termo em inglês.

Comment: Pois, pessoalmente, também sou da tua opinião, até me parece algo do "outro mundo" quando leio _entre-navegadores_. :) Coloquei a pergunta porque não sei se podemos classificar como termo-técnico e manter como sugeres... Fica o meu +1 na tua sugestão.)

Comment: **Ps:** não "aguentei" e tive que colocar a pergunta, um pouco + de trabalho em _moderação_, mas estou a acumular tabs no navegador com perguntas à espera de confirmação aqui no META, o que me parece que vai demorar o seu tempo até a termos! :(

Comment: Pois é @Zuul, acho que vamos ter de pensar diferente: considerar como consenso aquilo que foi discutido até aqui (contanto que tenha havido discussão), com quem se dispôs a participar. E estarmos sempre abertos a retomar as discussões e, se for o caso, alterarmos as regras. Senão corremos o risco de continuar sem regra nenhuma por meses.

Comment: Sim, concordo plenamente! Mais vale começar a deixar algumas coisas que já contam com X votos como "regra" e mais tarde reavaliar quando outras respostas/ideias tiverem surgido! Esperar que um maior número de participantes apareça é adiar as decisões ao infinito! _(neste momento pelo menos é o que parece...)_

Comment: Concordo com tudo. É o que devemos fazer. Quanto a tag acho que assim que alguém criar o cross-browser será relacionada com entre-navegadores. Não precisamos nos preocupar tanto com o fato de usar algo que pode ter um sinônimo. Já falei em outra resposta, teremos uma quantidade bem maior de sinônimos que o SO por causa da diferença das (no mínimo) 3 línguas que usamos aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Aqui na empresa utilizamos o termo "multi-dispositivo" como tradução para o termo `cross-device`. Apesar de não ser uma tradução 100% fiel, funciona bem e repassa a ideia do termo utilizado.

Eu ainda prefiro o original `cross-browser`, mas `multi-navegador` me parece uma opção viável.

Answer (score 2):

Porquê traduzir tags?

Há determinadas coisas cuja tradução só iria complicar.

Se pretendermos traduzir tudo, teremos também de utilizar a tradução para `Tag`.

Esta pergunta teria que ser: "Tradução adequada para a **etiqueta** “Cross-browser”.

Todos os termos específicos a qualquer tecnologia ou domínio não deveriam ser traduzidos.

Por isso, a tradução para `Cross-browser` é `Cross-browser`

Answer (score 1):

Dado tratarem-se de duas palavras, eu sugeria a tradução de ambas com posterior aplicação da separação por hífen:

- cross = entre
- browsers = navegadores

## Tag *base*

[entre-navegadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entre-navegadores)

Answer (score 1):

Baseando-se na do Zuul, minha sugestão seria `inter-navegador`. Geralmente o que acontece entre múltiplos membros de uma mesma classe se chama de "inter"... inter-classe, inter-estadual, inter-municipal e afins.